# widgetcolumn пропадает если перезагрузить стор на неактивном табе

Tags: javascript, extjs

При клике по левому гриду, перезагружаются два грида которые расположены в TabPanel. 
На активном табе виджет появляется, а на неактивном нет. Появляется снова если перезагрузить на пагинаторе или добавить новую строку в грид.

Может кто-то знает возможные причины. Или как обновить колонку виджетов при переключении табов.

```
Ext.define('SOM.JS.view.SearchAttributeViewModel_grid', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.SearchAttributeViewModel_grid',

    formulas: {
        //current searchAttr is bound to automatically published selection
        currentSearchAttr: {
            bind: '{grdSearchAttribute.selection}',
            get: function(searchAttr){
                var rec;
                if(Ext.isArray(searchAttr)){
                    rec = searchAttr[0];
                } else {
                    rec = searchAttr;
                }
                this.set('current.searchAttr', rec);
                return rec;
            }
        }
    },

    stores: {
        storeSearchAttribute: {
            model: 'SOM.JS.model.SearchAttributeModel',
            sorters: {
                property: 'SORDER',
                direction: 'ASC'
            },
            remoteSort: true,
            listeners: {
                datachanged: 'onDataChanged',
                beforeload: 'onBeforeLoad',
                scope: 'controller'
            },
            searchParams: {
                Config_Id: {bindTo: 'currentObject.ObjectRec.ID'}
            }
        }
    }
    });

    Ext.define('SOM.JS.view.SearchAttributeView_grid', {
    extend: 'EcxUtils5.BaseClass.GridView',
    alias: 'widget.SearchAttributeView_grid',
    viewModel: {
        type: 'SearchAttributeViewModel_grid'
    },
    bind: {
        store: '{storeSearchAttribute}',
        selection: '{current.searchAttr}'
    },
    selModel: {
        mode: 'SINGLE'
    },
    reference: 'grdSearchAttribute',
    id: 'IDgrdSearchAttribute',
    dockedItems: [
        {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            dock: 'top',
            cls: 'Ecx MainActionTlbr',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    reference: 'btnAddSearchAttribute',
                    text: 'New Attribute',
                    icon: EcxUtils.Form.getIconURL('add'),
                    handler: 'onActionNew'
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    columns: [
        {
            xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
            menuDisabled: true,
            id: 'idWidgSearch',
            width: 50,
            widget: {
                //defaultBindProperty: null,
                xtype: 'container',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        icon: EcxUtils.Form.getIconURL('cog'),
                        menu: {
                            xtype: 'menu',
                            items: [{text:'TEMP'}],
                            listeners: {
                                activate: 'onMenuActivate',  
                                scope: 'controller'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            menuDisabled: true,
            sortable: false,
            xtype: 'actioncolumn',
            width: 45,
            align: 'center',
            items: [
                {
                    icon: EcxUtils.Form.getIconURL('arrow_up'),
                    tooltip: 'Order Up',
                    command: 'UP',
                    handler: 'directOrder'
                },
                {
                    icon: EcxUtils.Form.getIconURL('arrow_down'),
                    tooltip: 'Order Down',
                    command: 'DOWN',
                    handler: 'directOrder'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            text: 'Id',
            dataIndex: 'ID',
            width: 60,
            hidden: true
        }
        ///
    ]

});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: После релоада]

Comment: Как я понял, у widgetcolumn id = 'idWidgSearch'. Возможно есть еще элемент с таким id, что может быть причиной бага. В ExtJS у компонентов поле id лучше вообще не использовать.

Comment: id = 'idWidgSearch' — это вариация попыток решения бага. Изначально id не было.

Comment: Можно ссылку на fiddle с примером?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Повесил на tabChange, listeners.

```
grid.getView().refresh();
```